# php confirm box after some codes

Tags: php, box, confirm

```
<?PHP
$cFile = $_FILES["sourcefile"];
$client=$_POST["client"];
$folder=$_POST["folder"];

require_once "Classes/PHPExcel.php";
$excel = "accounts.xlsx";
$excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($excel);
$excelObj = $excelReader->load($excel);
$ftpadress = $excelObj->getSheet(0);
$lastRow = $ftpadress->getHighestRow();

$x=1;
while($x<=$lastRow) {
if($ftpadress->getCell('A'.$x)->getValue()==$client){
$dmethod        =$ftpadress->getCell('B'.$x)->getValue();
$adress         =$ftpadress->getCell('C'.$x)->getValue();
$username       =$ftpadress->getCell('D'.$x)->getValue();
$pass           =$ftpadress->getCell('E'.$x)->getValue();
$port           =$ftpadress->getCell('F'.$x)->getValue();
}
$x++;
}
//confirm box Start
echo "CLIENT : $client";
echo "ADRESSS : $adress";
echo "USERNAME : $username";
echo "Are you sure?;
//confirm box End

---if result==no;{
---die;}
---else{
---echo "smart is the new sexy!";
---}

?>
```

I want to add these "echo"s in to a confirm box.
If OK clicked, it will move to next codes.
if Cancel clicked, it will die;

I've searched but everyone offered "onclick" confirm box. I want to show confirm button after some codes.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I want to ask user "are you sure?" after getting "CLIENT, ADRESS etc.. information".

Comment: PHP can't do this... nothing is executed on the client side, use javascript instead

Comment: ok, but can I add javasicript in here and without any button. and which code can I use?

Comment: there is even something easier : just display your data on a page with a link `continue` redirecting the user to the page with the rest of the code

Comment: I also think about that but at that time I have to post all inputs again to target php :)